# Python MySql make array of a Query

Tags: python, mysql, arrays, mysql-python

I have a MySql query, everything works fine, but I want to make an array of each row to be used out of the query

Here is my code:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user="root", passwd="", db="seliso")

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE contador = " + "'" + userContador + "'")

results = cursor.fetchall()

for row in results:
    rfc = row[1]
    clave = row[2]
```

**Example of I want to do:**

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user="root", passwd="", db="seliso")

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE contador = " + "'" + userContador + "'")

results = cursor.fetchall()

for row in results:
    rfc = row[1]
    clave = row[2]

$arrayRFC = ["rfc1", "rfc2", "rfc3"]
$arrayClave = ["clave1", "clave2", "clave3"]
```

How can this be acheived?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get that with:

```
for i in zip(*results):
    print(list(i))
```

Further, you should not use string concatenation like that for reasons of [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Instead do:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE contador = %s",(userContador,))
```

Where `%s` is the parameter style per: http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html

Comment: Thank you so much, you are the best! :)

Comment: Cheers, mate. Happy coding to you :-)

Comment: but how can I use it out of "for:"

Comment: bro sorry, that isn't what I need. I need to use de "row" array out of "for:"

Comment: mmm.. here is a php example: <?php
$r=mysql_query("select * from clientes");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r)){
 $cls[]=$row;
}

print(json_encode($cls));
mysql_close($con);
?>

Comment: well, "for: I have array = [1,2,4,5]" If I print "array" inside the "for:" it will display "1,2,3,4,5" but if I print "array" outside "for:" it will display "1" I need to display all the strings in the array